# Choosing appropriate CSS selectors

Tags: python-3.x, css-selectors, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to find the appropriate CSS selectors for the value of `Diluted EPS (ttm)` from:

`https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/key-statistics?ltr=1]`.

Finding the correct CSS selectors for the stock price itself was easy, I just went into the developer tools, looked for the desired value and copied the CSS selectors. When I do the same looking for the above mentioned value I receive the following:

```
div.Mb\(10px\):nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(4) > table:nth-child(2) > tbody:nth-child(1) > tr:nth-child(7) > td:nth-child(2)
```

That line however does not deliver the desired value in Python using the beautifulsoup module.

If I literally copy the line with my value it gives:

```
<td class="Fz(s) Fw(500) Ta(end)">8.31</td>
```

How can I choose the correct CSS selector to get my speecific value?

I'm fairly new to Python so excuse that question.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead of using a specific class, they are selecting based on the "nth-element", so you would have to traverse the DOM to find the "nth-element" based on that first line you provided. There might not be a single class on that field that you can pull directly.

Answer (score 0):

CSS selectors were designed **only to select elements**, never to find their contents as that is all they were needed for in styling. Using CSS selectors, you can only tell BeautifulSoup to find the element you are looking for, never the contents of the element. However to retrieve the actual contents of the element (the value between the tags), **you must use the** `contents` **attribute.**

In your case, it seems like you would want to use the following code to retrieve the value (inserting your own selector):

```
soup.select("YOUR-SELECTOR-HERE").contents
>>> 8.33
```

Your selector didn't work for me, but that could be for a number of reasons, so you can fill in your working selectors there.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try that!

Answer (score 0):

On the page you provided, the class attributes do not individually identify elements on the page.

As @felix-guo mentioned in the comments; you'll need to traverse the soup's trees using the nth element to access the data.

Try something along the lines of:

```
all_tables = soup.find_all('table', {'class': 'table-qsp-stats'})
income_statements = all_tables[4]
diluted_eps = income_statements.find_all('tr')[6].find_all('td')[1].get_text()
```